# close a dialog on background image touch libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to close a dialog on background touch but it always goes in the else condition

```
stage.addListener(new InputListener(){
                    @Override
                    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                        if(stage.hit(x,y,true).equals(bg)) {
                            System.out.println("in th if");
                            dialog.addAction(rotateTo(90, .30f, Interpolation.smooth2));
                            dialog.hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("int the else");
                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                });
```

Comment: What object is `stage`?

Comment: why not just use an input listener on the background?

Comment: @azizbekian I might have misunderstood your question sir, but it's this https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d

Comment: @p.streef we tried adding an input listener to the stage but it will close the dialog even if you touch inside the diallog. We want to close it only if you press outside the dialog. an input listener for the background (stage) will detect all inputs

Comment: The stage is not the background. The stage is the thing that holds all the actors. input listener on stage calls all the other imput listeners. If you handle stage first and not the rest it will overrule the rest. However, if you just add the background as an Image it is itself an actor. and if it is behind the dialog (lower z-index, or added before the dialog) the input will not go through the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work, but didn't test.

Dialog is already set up to receive all touchDown input while it's visible, even if the touch is outside its bounds, so simply give it a listener that hides it if the touch is outside its bounds:

```
    dialog.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            if (x < 0 || x > dialog.getWidth() || y < 0 || y > dialog.getHeight()){
                dialog.hide();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This assumes `dialog` is final or a member field so you can access it from the listener.

I think the reason your code doesn't work is that `stage.hit(...)` will always return the `dialog` regardless of coordinates since Dialogs are set up to absorb all input.